# Arch boot: Echo asterisks when typing cryptsetup password

Tags: arch-linux, boot, initramfs, mkinitcpio

I am trying to setup my initramfs with `mkinitcpio -P` so it decrypts my LUKS/LVM partition containing the root file system on startup.

I followed the steps on [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/System_configuration) . Everything already works fine, by adding HOOKs `encrypt` and `lvm2` among others, see `mkinitcpio.conf` below.

Now I would like to have asterisk characters being echoed when I enter the password for the LUKS encrypted partition.

I found a nice command line tool for doing so: `systemd-ask-password`.

So I modified `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` accordingly, so it adds `systemd-ask-password` as a binary, and `/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/encrypt` to use systemd-ask-password for querying the password and pipe the output to cryptsetup and ran `mkinitcpio -P`.

But it does not mask the password characters with asterisks! It echoes them one by one, which is not secure and not what I intended. In a readily booted system, in a regular terminal and bash, it works perfectly fine. But it seems like the "terminal" during bootup behaves differently. Or the `systemd-ask-password` command behaves differently in that environment.

How can I get systemd-ask-password to work properly in the boot terminal environment?

Or: Is there a better way to achieve what I want, to echo the password characters as asterisks?

/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/encrypt:

```
#!/usr/bin/ash

run_hook() {
    modprobe -a -q dm-crypt >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ "${quiet}" = "y" ] && CSQUIET=">/dev/null"

    # Get keyfile if specified
    ckeyfile="/crypto_keyfile.bin"
    if [ -n "$cryptkey" ]; then
        IFS=: read ckdev ckarg1 ckarg2 <<EOF
$cryptkey
EOF

        if [ "$ckdev" = "rootfs" ]; then
            ckeyfile=$ckarg1
        elif resolved=$(resolve_device "${ckdev}" ${rootdelay}); then
            case ${ckarg1} in
                *[!0-9]*)
                    # Use a file on the device
                    # ckarg1 is not numeric: ckarg1=filesystem, ckarg2=path
                    mkdir /ckey
                    mount -r -t "$ckarg1" "$resolved" /ckey
                    dd if="/ckey/$ckarg2" of="$ckeyfile" >/dev/null 2>&1
                    umount /ckey
                    ;;
                *)
                    # Read raw data from the block device
                    # ckarg1 is numeric: ckarg1=offset, ckarg2=length
                    dd if="$resolved" of="$ckeyfile" bs=1 skip="$ckarg1" count="$ckarg2" >/dev/null 2>&1
                    ;;
            esac
        fi
        [ ! -f ${ckeyfile} ] && echo "Keyfile could not be opened. Reverting to passphrase."
    fi

    if [ -n "${cryptdevice}" ]; then
        DEPRECATED_CRYPT=0
        IFS=: read cryptdev cryptname cryptoptions <<EOF
$cryptdevice
EOF
    else
        DEPRECATED_CRYPT=1
        cryptdev="${root}"
        cryptname="root"
    fi

    # This may happen if third party hooks do the crypt setup
    if [ -b "/dev/mapper/${cryptname}" ]; then
        echo "Device ${cryptname} already exists, not doing any crypt setup."
        return 0
    fi

    warn_deprecated() {
        echo "The syntax 'root=${root}' where '${root}' is an encrypted volume is deprecated"
        echo "Use 'cryptdevice=${root}:root root=/dev/mapper/root' instead."
    }

    set -f
    OLDIFS="$IFS"; IFS=,
    for cryptopt in ${cryptoptions}; do
        case ${cryptopt} in
            allow-discards)
                cryptargs="${cryptargs} --allow-discards"
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Encryption option '${cryptopt}' not known, ignoring." >&2
                ;;
        esac
    done
    set +f
    IFS="$OLDIFS"
    unset OLDIFS

    if resolved=$(resolve_device "${cryptdev}" ${rootdelay}); then
        if cryptsetup isLuks ${resolved} >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            [ ${DEPRECATED_CRYPT} -eq 1 ] && warn_deprecated
            dopassphrase=1
            # If keyfile exists, try to use that
            if [ -f ${ckeyfile} ]; then
                if eval cryptsetup --key-file ${ckeyfile} open --type luks ${resolved} ${cryptname} ${cryptargs} ${CSQUIET}; then
                    dopassphrase=0
                else
                    echo "Invalid keyfile. Reverting to passphrase."
                fi
            fi
            # Ask for a passphrase
            if [ ${dopassphrase} -gt 0 ]; then
                echo ""
                echo "A password is required to access the ${cryptname} volume:"

                #loop until we get a real password
                while ! eval systemd-ask-password | cryptsetup open --type luks ${resolved} ${cryptname} ${cryptargs} ${CSQUIET}; do
                    sleep 2;
                done
            fi
            if [ -e "/dev/mapper/${cryptname}" ]; then
                if [ ${DEPRECATED_CRYPT} -eq 1 ]; then
                    export root="/dev/mapper/root"
                fi
            else
                err "Password succeeded, but ${cryptname} creation failed, aborting..."
                return 1
            fi
        elif [ -n "${crypto}" ]; then
            [ ${DEPRECATED_CRYPT} -eq 1 ] && warn_deprecated
            msg "Non-LUKS encrypted device found..."
            if echo "$crypto" | awk -F: '{ exit(NF == 5) }'; then
                err "Verify parameter format: crypto=hash:cipher:keysize:offset:skip"
                err "Non-LUKS decryption not attempted..."
                return 1
            fi
            exe="cryptsetup open --type plain $resolved $cryptname $cryptargs"
            IFS=: read c_hash c_cipher c_keysize c_offset c_skip <<EOF
$crypto
EOF
            [ -n "$c_hash" ]    && exe="$exe --hash '$c_hash'"
            [ -n "$c_cipher" ]  && exe="$exe --cipher '$c_cipher'"
            [ -n "$c_keysize" ] && exe="$exe --key-size '$c_keysize'"
            [ -n "$c_offset" ]  && exe="$exe --offset '$c_offset'"
            [ -n "$c_skip" ]    && exe="$exe --skip '$c_skip'"
            if [ -f "$ckeyfile" ]; then
                exe="$exe --key-file $ckeyfile"
            else
                echo ""
                echo "A password is required to access the ${cryptname} volume:"
            fi
            eval "$exe $CSQUIET"

            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                err "Non-LUKS device decryption failed. verify format: "
                err "      crypto=hash:cipher:keysize:offset:skip"
                return 1
            fi
            if [ -e "/dev/mapper/${cryptname}" ]; then
                if [ ${DEPRECATED_CRYPT} -eq 1 ]; then
                    export root="/dev/mapper/root"
                fi
            else
                err "Password succeeded, but ${cryptname} creation failed, aborting..."
                return 1
            fi
        else
            err "Failed to open encryption mapping: The device ${cryptdev} is not a LUKS volume and the crypto= paramater was not specified."
        fi
    fi
    rm -f ${ckeyfile}
}

# vim: set ft=sh ts=4 sw=4 et:
```

/etc/mkinitcpio.conf:

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
MODULES=()

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=(systemd-ask-password)

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=()

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS=(base)
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect keyboard keymap consolefont modconf block encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)

# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, zstd compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="zstd"
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but an alternative you have is to switch to systemd init (see [Mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mkinitcpio)). You may then replace the mkinitcpio `encrypt` hook with the `sd-encrypt` one, which behaves the way you are looking for by default.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, sorry it took so long. Replaced the following lines as follows:
`BINARIES=()`
...
`HOOKS=(base systemd autodetect keyboard sd-vconsole modconf block sd-encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)'
And it works fine, exactly as I wanted it. Thank you! Yes, it did not directly answer my question, but pointed me towards this good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't have a direct answer to the first of my exact original questions (how to get `systemd-ask-password` to work properly in a busybox environment), but achieved what I wanted by using systemd instead of busybox for booting. For this, I modified the following lines in the files:

`/etc/mkinitcpio.conf:`

```
[...]
BINARIES=()
[...]
HOOKS=(base systemd autodetect keyboard sd-vconsole modconf block sd-encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)
[...]
```

And now it behaves exactly as I wanted it: When I enter the LUKS passphrase, it echoes every character that I type as an asterisk `*`, so I have my deisred visual feedback now.

Thank you very much @fra-san for pointing me towards this solution!